# Application or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a query that runs when a workbook is opened. If the query is refreshed to a new sheet (panel) I am not sure how to correctly modify the code below to reflect this change. Thank you  .

Trying to use the range in J-O to populate the data validation in A2, but as of now I get an error with the bold part highlighted.

```
' Select Patient

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets(“panel”)
    lastrow = Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
With Selection.Validation
    End With
    With .Range("A2").Validation
        .Delete
        **.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
             xlBetween, Formula1:="=$J$1:$O$1" & lastrow**
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: use `Set lastrow = Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @ja72 - You do not need `Set` to assign a *long* (the row number) but there should be a period (.) in front of `.Cells`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a range, but yes `.Row` returns a row number. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

So for these kinds of errors in VBA I like to make sure all data that can be declared with `Dim` has been done.  This way I can take a look at each variable and see the value of it for manual error checking.

For example I took

```
Formula1:="=$J$1:$O$1" & lastrow
```

And changed it to be a `formula` string which I dim at the start:

```
Dim formula as String
```

then after you get the last row you can debug the variable and see that it is equal to (for example)

```
"=$J$1:$O$113"
```

Now to test this out manually I tried to add a data validation list with that as it's source.  That is where I got the error:

[image: error dialog]

This error message clearly sums it up.  You cannot have a data validation list spanning multiple columns.  You need to change your design to match what Excel can do.

To further double check this, I went back and changed the formula to:

```
formula = "=$J$1:$J$" & lastrow
```

Which ran perfectly smooth, no errors and a nice drop-down list appears in "A2"

The full sub I used is this:

```
Sub Macro1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim formula As String

With Sheets("panel")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    formula = "=panel!$J$1:$J$" & lastrow
End With

With Sheets("annovar")
    With .Range("A2").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
             xlBetween, Formula1:=formula
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is have the dropdown in A2 be populated with just the values in column J, but columns J-O have values in them (returned from a query).  In the data validation in A2 the user selects the case and the values associated with that case are populated.  Thank you :).

Comment: @user3665765 So then probably `formula = "=$J$1:$J$" & lastrow` is what you want to create the drop-down of just column J.  You will need to add some formulas to get the corresponding data in columns `K-O` probably some `INDEX` and `MATCH`

Comment: I do not get a dropdown in A2 with the values from column J... I get no dropdown.  Thank you :).

Comment: @user3665765 I added the full sub

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean by full Sub (learning VB).  Thank you :).

Comment: @user3665765 Look at my edit, I mean I added the full code to create the dropdown.

Comment: sorry I just saw that (sometimes I get a delay using ie, but chrome is fine),

Comment: Minor point but `lastrow = Cells(.Rows.Count, ...` should have a prefix period before `Cells` to adopt the parent worksheet expressed by the `With ...` statement directly above it.

Comment: I am going to post the full code in another post as I am not gettibng a dropdown in A2.  Thank you :).

Comment: I see the dropdown in A2 on the sheet "panel", however I am trying to get the dropdoen and the other values on the sheet "annovar".  So do I need to specify that in the With .Range?  Thank you :).

Comment: @user3665765 sure that is a quick change, see the updated code

Comment: Thank you for all your help I get a dropdown and will change the look-ups :).  I appreciate your help.

Comment: What would you recommend in terms of the INDEX/MATCH?  I will post the code,which is not working, I tried in another post called "lookup code between sheets".  Thank you :).